AWS S3 SDK Java v2 | Path Style access not working with S3EncryptionClient
I am getting below error while trying to read from  S3 bucket
I am trying to upgrade to AWS S3 SDK Java v2.
Exception:
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: 
No subject alternative DNS name matching my-bucket-name.us.s3.xxx.net found. 
Subject alternative DNS names in the certificate chain of 2 certificate(s): s3.xxx.net,*.s3.xxx.net

Dependency Used:

software.amazon.awssdk|s3|2.27.19
software.amazon.encryption.s3|amazon-s3-encryption-client-java| 3.2.1

AWS4 Canonical Request: 
GET test-file.txt
amz-sdk-invocation-id: some-number
amz-sdk-request:attempt=1; 
max=4
host:my-bucket-name.us.s3.xxx.net
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20240905T191849Z
x-amz-te:append-md5
amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-teUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD

I am trying to make the host with path style access. That is also not working
@Bean
public S3Client s3Client() {

ProxyConfiguration config = ProxyConfiguration.builder()
                .addNonProxyHost(nonProxy)
                .endpoint(URI.create(s3Endpoint))
                .build();

ApacheHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                .proxyConfiguration(config);

S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                .httpClientBuilder(clientBuilder)
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .endpointOverride(URI.create(s3Endpoint))
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                .forcePathStyle(Boolean.TRUE) //Setting this doesnt work
                .build();

return S3EncryptionClient.builder()
                .wrappedClient(s3Client)
                .endpointOverride(URI.create(s3Endpoint))
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .aesKey(originalKey)
                .enableLegacyUnauthenticatedModes(true)
                .enableLegacyWrappingAlgorithms(true)
}

It works fine when using AmazonS3EncryptionV2(from com.amazonaws|aws-java-sdk-s3|1.12.770) instead of S3EncryptionClient
